# React Native replace bundle.js

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to make a native modules, that can replace main.bundle.js inside application? If UI changes user will not have to update application, application will just pull new js bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There already are some libraries that do exactly that.

[react-native-auto-updater](https://github.com/aerofs/react-native-auto-updater) is only the client part that does the update on the device. [CodePush](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) on the other hand is a complete solution that also helps you distribute your code.